# Dimension of center of k[G]/rad k[G] where characteristic of k divides the order of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

Let *G* be a finite group and consider *k*[*G*] where *k* is a field. In the scenario where char(*k*) divides |*G*|, how can one show that the dimension of *Z*(*k*[G]/rad *k*[*G*]) is **strictly less** than dimension of *Z*(*k*[*G*])?

I'm trying to use this to show that in the case where char(*k*) divides |*G*|, the number of simple modules (up to isomorphism) is strictly less than no. of conjugacy classes of *G*. I'm aware of the fact that this can be answered using some knowledge of characters but I'm wondering if the above line of attack is also possible?

Remark: In the case where char(*k*) does not divide |*G*|, we have that rad(*k*[*G*]) is trivial since *k*[*G*] is semisimple and therefore *Z*(*k*[G]/rad *k*[*G*]) = *Z*(*k*[*G*]) and it can be shown that the number of simple modules is **at most** the number of conjugacy classes.

Thank you in advance for any light that can be shed on the matter! :)

Comment: Now posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Dimension of center of k\[G\]/rad k\[G\] when characteristic of k divides the order of G](https://mathoverflow.net/q/358050).